# How to make rails cache retrieval specific to a certain object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dalli

For bar_id = 1 a cache gets formed on first access. but even if bar_id is changed to 2 later on the values of 1 is retained. How do I make it work across bar_id(s)

```
 @foo = Rails.cache.fetch("foo_by_id", expires_in: 10.minutes) do
    Foo.where(:search => params['search'], :bar_id => params['bar_id']).first
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cache key must include any dynamic data you want to separate your cache by.
In your case the cache key must include bar_id. What I'd do is:

```
@foo = Rails.cache.fetch("foo_by_id:#{params['bar_id']}", expires_in: 10.minutes) do
    Foo.where(:search => params['search'], :bar_id => params['bar_id']).first
 end
```

Comment: Thanks very much Erez, am pretty sure that this is the right fix. Are there any other patterns which I can use with respect to caching

Comment: @Rpj it is tell since your question is too general. If you have anything which is more concrete please post another question and I'd be glad to try and help.